# Sharepoint 2013 on premise mapped drive office 2016 drag drop uploading corrupt files with 0kb

Tags: sharepoint-server, drag-and-drop, mapped-folder

When I have a mapped drive to my sharepoint on premise document library and try to drag / drop a folder from my desktop, the files are being uploaded as empty / corrupt files for some users, but working fine for some other users. User permissions are exactly the same for all users.. what could the problem be?

Comment: is everyone (apart from you) accessing it from Sharepoint web UI or all users use as well mapped drive?. From your description I am not sure where you have the corruption.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Check the user permission for the users who have the empty or corrupt files on the file level.
2. Remove the users from the document library and re-grant the user permission for those users.
3. Create a new document library and map drive for the document library to check if the same issue will occur.